# Do particles go after or between question words?

Tags: grammar, usage, particles, word-order

Recently, I have realized something interesting:

The following sentences are from Japanese lyrics of different songs, so they must be grammatically correct:

> 誰よりも輝く君を見て
>
> 誰にも話せない
>
> 誰の心にも、大切な場所がある
>
> いくつもの季節が通り過ぎて

From the first three sentences, it seems that も always comes after the question word, as well as the particle that's with it(誰より、誰に、誰の心に). However, when it comes to the fourth, why is it suddenly いくつもの季節, instead of いくつの季節も, like 誰の心にも? Is it because of the absence of に? If use いくつもの季節 with に, would it become いくつもの季節に or いくつの季節にも?

Comment: the positioning of も affects the meaning of the sentence. I don't think it has anything to do with whether a word is interrogative or not.

Comment: @Shurim could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether the word marked by も is a question word or not is not important. In fact, the position of も remains unchanged when 誰 is replaced with 彼 in the first three examples.

> 彼よりも輝く君を見て

> 彼にも話せない

> 彼の心にも、大切な場所がある

As for the last one, (*) いくつの季節 is ungrammatical to begin with.

You wouldn’t ask:

> (*) いくつの季節がありますか。

It should be:

> 季節はいくつありますか。

いくつも *does* have a similar structure to 何も, 誰も, どこも and so on. However, like いつも, it is listed as a separate entry in dictionaries. Its meaning is close to たくさん when used in an affirmative sentence and あまり in a negative one. Like たくさん (but not あまり), it can take the form いくつもの to modify a noun.

You shouldn’t chop it up in the middlle, just like you shouldn’t split いつも into いつ and も.